# pyqt5でグラフをダブルクリックしたときに保存フォルダーを開き、グラフの保存をしたい

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

pyqt5とmatplotlibを使い、グラフをGUIに表示します。この時グラフを左クリックしながらドラッグすることで視点変更、右クリックしながらドラッグすることでスケール変更が出来ます。ここでグラフをダブルクリックすると保存フォルダーが開かれ、グラフの図を保存することが出来ます。しかし、保存フォルダーを閉じた後にマウスを動かすとグラフの視点が変更されます。恐らく保存フォルダーを開いたことにより、左クリックのリリースイベントが起こらずに、グラフをクリックしたままドラッグしている扱いになっていると思われます。どのように修正すればよいのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QPushButton, QFileDialog)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D


class MyCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        width=6
        height=6
        dpi=100

        self.check_label=True

        self.color="#ffffff"
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        
        self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)
        self.axes.set_box_aspect((1,1,1))
        self.axes.dist=12

        self.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press) 
        self.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_button_release)

    def on_button_press(self,event):
        if event.button==1:
            if event.dblclick:
                self.set_save()
            else:
                pass
            
    def on_button_release(self,event):
        print("button release")

    def set_save(self):
        filename,_ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "save",filter="PNG Files(*.png) ;; JPG Files(*.jpg) ;; All Files ()")
        if len(filename) == 0:
            return
        self.fig.savefig(filename)
        
class MyMplCanvas(MyCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.win=parent 
        super(MyMplCanvas,self).__init__(parent)

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        
        x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        Z = np.sin(X)+ np.cos(Y)
        
        self.canvas=MyMplCanvas(self)
        self.canvas.axes.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
        self.canvas.axes.set_title("graph",fontsize=20,c="k")
        
        layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout1)
        
        self.show()

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    #sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 恐らく保存フォルダーを開いたことにより、左クリックのリリースイベントが起こらずに、グラフをクリックしたままドラッグしている扱いになっていると思われます。

見たところ、まさにその通りという動きをしていますね。

`on_button_press`, `on_button_release` それぞれの `event.guiEvent.type()` を通じて、 バックエンドとなる Qt のイベントを見てみると、

- `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress`
- `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease`
- `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick`
- `QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease`

の順に呼び出されていることがわかります。

ところが、 `MouseButtonDblClick` の処理中に `self.set_save()` を呼び出してしまうと、 その後の `MouseButtonRelease` の処理を matplotlib 側が見落としてしまうようです。

---

さて、 どう修正すれば良いかについてですが、 `self.set_save()` の処理の前に `MouseButtonRelease` のイベントがトリガーされれば、とりあえず目的を果たせそうです。

いくつかやり方は考えられそうですが、手っ取り早そうなのは、以下の 2通り 思いつきます。

1. ダブルクリックでフラグだけ立てて、 `on_button_release` で `set_save()` する
2. `on_button_press` で `set_save()` 呼ぶ前に、 強制的に Qt の `MouseButtonRelease` イベントをトリガーさせる

このうち (2) の実装例ですが、 `MyCanvas` が継承している `FigureCanvasQTAgg` は、しれっと `QtWidgets.QWidget` を継承しているので、 [`QtTest.QTest.mouseRelease`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#mouseRelease) を使って以下のように呼び出すことが可能です。

```diff
from PyQt5 import QtTest, QtCore

...

    def on_button_press(self,event):
        if event.button==1:
            if event.dblclick:
                QtTest.QTest.mouseRelease(self, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
                self.set_save()
```

Comment: `QtTest.QTest.mouseRelease(self.canvas, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)`のままでは変化がありませんでしたが、`self.canvas`の所を`self`にした所、無事動作しました。いずれにせよ、お陰様で解決いたしました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: よく確認したら、 `MyCanvas` 自身が `FigureCanvas` を継承していて、 そちらに figure が紐付けられていました (`self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)` の処理は無駄)。 そのため、ご認識の通り `mouseRelease` の第一引数は `self` とするのが正解です。

Answer (score 1):

既に解決済みですが、参考までに別回答を投稿します。

原因としてはダブルクリックの2回目の mouse release event が QFileDialog widget に取られてしまうからです。

[QWidget Events](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html#events)

> mouseReleaseEvent() is called when a mouse button is released. A widget receives mouse release events when it has received the corresponding mouse press event. This means that if the user presses the mouse inside your widget, then drags the mouse somewhere else before releasing the mouse button, your widget receives the release event. **There is one exception: if a popup menu appears while the mouse button is held down, this popup immediately steals the mouse events**.

FigureCanvasQTAgg には各種 event の callback function が登録されている `callbacks` attribute がありますので、これを使って mouse release event に紐付けられている callback function を実行させることができます。

```py
    def on_button_press(self, event):
        if event.button == 1:
            if event.dblclick:
                self.callbacks.process('button_release_event', event)
                self.set_save()
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: 分かりやすい解説まで添えて頂きありがとうございます！こちらの方の方法でも動作を確認致しました。